# Javascript asynchronous behavior with Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, web-scraping, async-await

I am extremely confused about the async behavior of JS.

I have a CSV file that contains a list of URL which needs to be scraped. And the result should then be added to a database row by row in a for loop.

```
fs.readFile("./file.csv", async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    let results = await neatCsv(data);
    db.connect();

    results.forEach(async row => {
      let ad = await kijiji.Ad.Get(row.url);
      let statement = "INSERT INTO Kijiji SET ?";

      let column = {
        uuid: uuid.v1(),
        url: ad.url,
        attributes: JSON.stringify(ad.attributes),
        latitude: ad.attributes.location.latitude,
        longitude: ad.attributes.location.longitude
      };
      const query = util.promisify(db.query).bind(db);
      await query(statement, column)
        .then()
        .catch(e => {
          throw e;
        });
    });

    const end = util.promisify(db.end).bind(db);
    await end()
      .then()
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        return failure({ status: e });
      });
});
```

The expected behavior for this piece of code should be synchronous, because from my understanding,`await kijiji.Ad.Get(row.url);` and `await query(statement, column)` behave as if its synchronous because `await` makes the program wait till the promise is fulfilled.

However, I am getting the following error message

> Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.`because`await db.end()` gets called first.

My main question is, how do I end my DB connection without end connection before my result array loop is completed?

Update: I converted forEach into a for loop, and I am using bulk insertion instead

```
fs.readFile("./src/file.csv", async (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  let results = await neatCsv(data);
  db.connect();
  values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    let row = results[i];
    console.log(count);
    count++;
    let ad = await kijiji.Ad.Get(row.url);
    console.log(ad);
    let column = [
      uuid.v1(),
      ad.url,
      JSON.stringify(ad.attributes),
      ad.attributes.location.latitude,
      ad.attributes.location.longitude
    ];
    values.push(column);
  }
  let statement =
    "INSERT INTO Kijiji (uuid, url, attributes, latitude, longitude) SET ?";

  const query = util.promisify(db.query).bind(db);
  await query(statement, values)
    .then()
    .catch(e => {
      throw e;
    });
  db.end();
});
```

But the execution is extremely slow, maybe around 1-2 seconds per URL, when foreach took about a few milliseconds. Why is this?

Comment: using `await` in `forEach` never results in what you want - use a regular `for` loop instead

Comment: that process seems slow, where you just insert one at the time. isn't there a bulk insert option?

Comment: Yes I'll looking into bulk insert. But my main question is - is it possible to make javascript asynch code into sync. Because .end is being called too early.

Comment: For some reason, for loop is much much slower....

Comment: Looks like you should take another look on some ES6 tutorial regarding Promises and async. For now it's looks like you'd just put `await` and `async` operators everywhere you could and hoping to get lucky with that.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I think I have understanding of promise (await makes async code wait by waiting for the promise to fulfill before moving on). If there is something I am lacking, I am all ears. Thank you.

Comment: *is it possible to make javascript asynch code into sync* - no, that would require time travel or psychic ability - one cant' predict the future

Comment: `await makes async code wait` sort of, yes, but never us it in a `.forEach` as it won't work like you think it would - use a regular for loop - as I stated 50 minutes ago in the first comment

Comment: Jaromanda, I added an update where I took your suggestion and used a `for` loop instead. But my execution of `let ad = await kijiji.Ad.Get(row.url);` becomes very slow. 700 records took about 3 seconds for `ForEach` while my `for loop` is still running....

Comment: Don't use await with .then(), you're blowing your own mind. await waits for a promise to resolve. When it returns you have the actual return value.

Comment: pguardiario, I took out `.then()` from ` await query(statement, values).catch(e => {
    throw e;
  });` but its still slow af.